# Mongodb get items nested in a collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, nested

In Mongo Database i have a collection store. I want to do a nested query and it doesn't seem like i am able to do it.

```
db.store.find()
```

this returns all of the collection.

Now each store has items

how would i get all items. Not just all items in one store but all items for every single store.

```
db.store.find(item:{i don't want a query i want them all})
```

The problem is i don't want to do a query on the items i just want all of them
Thanks for the input much appreciated

Edited  hmmk? well what i have tried is

when i type db.store.find()

```
        "_id" : ObjectId("52695741d6b0a8701a0000ad"),
        "name" : "Non Dui Nec LLP",
        "code" : "YFY37YEQ0VZ",
        "url" : "www.txvhmjkcyirjmb.com",
        "facebook_link" : "http://facebook.com/qhhonsm",
        "twitter_link" : "http://twitter.com/sqwmpbcqx",
        "items" : [
                {
                        "user_id" : 6,
                        "code" : "HKS29TGT1QE",
                        "name" : "Lorem Donec LLP",
                        "description" : "adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet, libero
et tristique pellentesque, tellus sem mollis dui, in sodales elit erat vitae ris
us. Duis a mi fringilla mi lacinia mattis. Integer eu lacus. Quisque imperdiet,
erat nonummy ultricies ornare, elit elit fermentum risus, at fringilla purus mau
ris a nunc. In at pede. Cras",
                        "featured" : "false",
                        "price" : 22278,
                        "quantity" : 2,
                        "views" : 229917,
                        "category_id" : 6,
                        "brand" : "Metus Sit Amet Inc.",
                        "rating" : 2,
                        "sale" : "true",
                        "sale_price" : 49437,
                        "online" : "true",
                        "store" : "true"
                },
                {
                        "user_id" : 6,
                        "code" : "UXS08MIR6ZV",
                        "name" : "Quisque Inc.",
                        "description" : "amet nulla. Donec non justo. Proin non
massa non ante bibendum ullamcorper. Duis cursus, diam at pretium aliquet,",
                        "featured" : "false",
                        "price" : 42511,
                        "quantity" : 8,
                        "views" : 372823,
                        "category_id" : 3,
                        "brand" : "Amet Metus PC",
                        "rating" : 5,
                        "sale" : "true",
                        "sale_price" : 31672,
                        "online" : "true",
                        "store" : "false"
                },
                {
                        "user_id" : 2,
                        "code" : "DBK19WNP4MK",
                        "name" : "Mauris Molestie Pharetra PC",
                        "description" : "volutpat. Nulla facilisis. Suspendisse
commodo tincidunt nibh. Phasellus nulla. Integer vulputate, risus a ultricies ad
ipiscing, enim mi tempor lorem, eget mollis lectus pede et risus. Quisque libero
 lacus, varius et, euismod et, commodo at, libero. Morbi accumsan laoreet ipsum.
 Curabitur consequat, lectus sit amet luctus vulputate, nisi sem semper",
                        "featured" : "true",
                        "price" : 39186,
                        "quantity" : 7,
                        "views" : 343691,
                        "category_id" : 5,
                        "brand" : "Malesuada LLP",
                        "rating" : 5,
                        "sale" : "false",
                        "sale_price" : 2929,
                        "online" : "true",
                        "store" : "true"
                },
                {
                        "user_id" : 2,
                        "code" : "VGT01QNU1AE",
                        "name" : "Amet Ornare Lectus Associates",
                        "description" : "ipsum. Phasellus vitae mauris sit amet
lorem semper auctor. Mauris vel turpis. Aliquam adipiscing lobortis risus. In mi
 pede, nonummy ut, molestie in, tempus eu, ligula. Aenean euismod mauris eu elit
. Nulla facilisi. Sed neque. Sed eget lacus. Mauris non dui nec urna suscipit no
nummy.",
                        "featured" : "true",
                        "price" : 25581,
                        "quantity" : 9,
                        "views" : 237448,
                        "category_id" : 1,
                        "brand" : "Risus Nulla Eget LLP",
                        "rating" : 5,
                        "sale" : "false",
                        "sale_price" : 25998,
                        "online" : "true",
                        "store" : "false"
                },
                {
                        "user_id" : 8,
                        "code" : "XYT91KLX5LC",
                        "name" : "Nunc Nulla Consulting",
                        "description" : "posuere vulputate, lacus. Cras interdum
. Nunc sollicitudin commodo ipsum. Suspendisse non leo. Vivamus nibh dolor, nonu
mmy ac, feugiat non, lobortis quis, pede.",
                        "featured" : "true",
                        "price" : 55233,
                        "quantity" : 8,
                        "views" : 102238,
                        "category_id" : 4,
                        "brand" : "Diam Eu Dolor Company",
                        "rating" : 4,
                        "sale" : "true",
                        "sale_price" : 28494,
                        "online" : "false",
                        "store" : "true"
                },
                {
                        "user_id" : 3,
                        "code" : "QGD53OAH0LJ",
                        "name" : "Tempus Eu Incorporated",
                        "description" : "non enim. Mauris quis turpis vitae puru
s gravida sagittis. Duis gravida. Praesent eu nulla at sem molestie sodales. Mau
ris blandit enim consequat purus. Maecenas libero est, congue a, aliquet vel, vu
lputate eu, odio. Phasellus at augue id ante dictum cursus. Nunc mauris elit,",
                        "featured" : "false",
                        "price" : 36669,
                        "quantity" : 10,
                        "views" : 129981,
                        "category_id" : 6,
                        "brand" : "Felis Purus Ac Company",
                        "rating" : 2,
                        "sale" : "false",
                        "sale_price" : 28753,
                        "online" : "true",
                        "store" : "true"
                },
                {
                        "user_id" : 9,
                        "code" : "NCI04XCU9OE",
                        "name" : "Ipsum Suspendisse Ltd",
                        "description" : "luctus vulputate, nisi sem semper erat,
 in consectetuer ipsum nunc id enim. Curabitur massa. Vestibulum accumsan neque
et nunc. Quisque ornare tortor",
                        "featured" : "true",
                        "price" : 67414,
                        "quantity" : 9,
                        "views" : 402667,
                        "category_id" : 4,
                        "brand" : "Quisque Porttitor PC",
                        "rating" : 5,
                        "sale" : "false",
                        "sale_price" : 10481,
                        "online" : "true",
                        "store" : "false"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52695741d6b0a8701a0000ae"),
        "name" : "Urna Institute",
        "code" : "YRH20JFJ0PW",
        "url" : "www.cfejurcgjtdvjf.com",
        "facebook_link" : "http://facebook.com/yzcbixz",
        "twitter_link" : "http://twitter.com/aehbnnloc",
        "items" : [
                {
                        "user_id" : 1,
                        "code" : "VEI96FAL1OQ",
                        "name" : "Ornare Facilisis Eget Corp.",
                        "description" : "arcu. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in f
aucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus ornare. Fusce m
ollis. Duis sit amet diam eu dolor egestas rhoncus. Proin nisl sem, consequat ne
c, mollis vitae, posuere at, velit. Cras lorem lorem, luctus ut, pellentesque eg
et, dictum placerat, augue. Sed molestie. Sed id",
                        "featured" : "true",
                        "price" : 67040,
                        "quantity" : 1,
                        "views" : 231128,
                        "category_id" : 2,
                        "brand" : "Sed Nec Consulting",
                        "rating" : 3,
                        "sale" : "false",
                        "sale_price" : 7198,
                        "online" : "false",
                        "store" : "true"
                },
                {
                        "user_id" : 3,
                        "code" : "JKT20ZIN1WE",
                        "name" : "Nulla Tempor Augue Incorporated",
                        "description" : "eleifend. Cras sed leo. Cras vehicula a
liquet libero. Integer in magna. Phasellus dolor elit, pellentesque a, facilisis
 non, bibendum sed, est. Nunc laoreet lectus quis massa. Mauris vestibulum, nequ
e sed dictum eleifend, nunc risus varius orci, in consequat enim diam vel arcu.
Curabitur ut",
                        "featured" : "true",
                        "price" : 51700,
                        "quantity" : 6,
                        "views" : 195004,
                        "category_id" : 5,
                        "brand" : "Mauris Institute",
                        "rating" : 4,
                        "sale" : "false",
                        "sale_price" : 44753,
                        "online" : "false",
                        "store" : "true"
                },
                {
                        "user_id" : 2,
                        "code" : "HNJ55IWD4TH",
                        "name" : "Ac Feugiat Limited",
                        "description" : "tristique ac, eleifend vitae, erat. Viv
amus nisi. Mauris nulla. Integer urna. Vivamus molestie dapibus ligula. Aliquam
erat",
                        "featured" : "false",
                        "price" : 70134,
                        "quantity" : 9,
                        "views" : 440143,
                        "category_id" : 4,
                        "brand" : "Eu Incorporated",
                        "rating" : 4,
                        "sale" : "false",
                        "sale_price" : 8213,
                        "online" : "false",
                        "store" : "false"
                },
                {
                        "user_id" : 3,
                        "code" : "OUZ13HAN7UV",
                        "name" : "At LLC",
                        "description" : "nonummy ipsum non arcu. Vivamus sit ame
t risus. Donec egestas. Aliquam nec enim. Nunc ut erat. Sed nunc est, mollis non
, cursus",
                        "featured" : "true",
                        "price" : 1468,
                        "quantity" : 10,
                        "views" : 371808,
                        "category_id" : 4,
                        "brand" : "Venenatis Associates",
                        "rating" : 4,
                        "sale" : "false",
                        "sale_price" : 48312,
                        "online" : "true",
                        "store" : "false"
                },
                {
                        "user_id" : 3,
                        "code" : "BAK14SFY4ZT",
                        "name" : "Consectetuer Euismod Corp.",
                        "description" : "Etiam ligula tortor, dictum eu, placera
t eget, venenatis a, magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Etiam laoreet, libero et tristique pellentesque, tellus sem mollis dui, in
 sodales elit erat vitae risus. Duis a mi fringilla mi lacinia mattis. Integer e
u lacus. Quisque imperdiet, erat nonummy",
                        "featured" : "true",
                        "price" : 95615,
                        "quantity" : 8,
                        "views" : 365175,
                        "category_id" : 3,
                        "brand" : "Donec Nibh Enim Incorporated",
                        "rating" : 3,
                        "sale" : "true",
                        "sale_price" : 12858,
                        "online" : "false",
                        "store" : "false"
                },
                {
                        "user_id" : 6,
                        "code" : "FNF49YPX4PQ",
                        "name" : "Morbi Institute",
                        "description" : "sit amet risus. Donec egestas. Aliquam
nec enim. Nunc ut erat. Sed nunc est, mollis non, cursus non, egestas a, dui. Cr
as pellentesque. Sed dictum. Proin eget odio. Aliquam vulputate ullamcorper magn
a. Sed eu eros. Nam consequat dolor vitae dolor. Donec fringilla. Donec feugiat
metus sit amet ante. Vivamus non",
                        "featured" : "true",
                        "price" : 94975,
                        "quantity" : 9,
                        "views" : 243181,
                        "category_id" : 3,
                        "brand" : "Elementum Purus Foundation",
                        "rating" : 1,
                        "sale" : "true",
                        "sale_price" : 49337,
                        "online" : "true",
                        "store" : "true"
                },
                {
                        "user_id" : 5,
                        "code" : "CAQ49OCW9SN",
                        "name" : "Sit Incorporated",
                        "description" : "Nunc ut erat. Sed nunc est, mollis non,
 cursus non, egestas",
                        "featured" : "false",
                        "price" : 98576,
                        "quantity" : 10,
                        "views" : 265153,
                        "category_id" : 3,
                        "brand" : "Fringilla Euismod Corporation",
                        "rating" : 5,
                        "sale" : "false",
                        "sale_price" : 7037,
                        "online" : "false",
                        "store" : "false"
                }
        ]
}
```

and i want to get all the items that all the stores have. I am not sure how to explain better
but i am trying to get all items in all stores. Let me know if it's still hard to understand. I can post more examples

Comment: Could you provide example document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```js
db.store.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$items"},
    {$project: {
        "user_id" : "$items.user_id",
        "code" : "$items.code",
        "name" : "$items.name",
        "description" : "$items.description",
        "featured" : "$items.featured",
        "quantity" : "$items.quantity",
        "views" : "$items.views",
        "category_id" : "$items.category_id",
        "brand" : "$items.brand",
        "rating" : "$items.rating",
        "sale" : "$items.sale",
        "sale_price" : "$items.sale_price",
        "online" : "$items.online",
        "store" : "$items.store",
        "_id": 0
    }}
])
```

`{$unwind: "$items"}` creates individual document for each subdocument in `items` array. It will give you array like this:

```js
[

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("52693d98e7792c81a7f4e5ad"),
        "items" : {
            "user_id" : 6,
            "code" : "HKS29TGT1QE",
            ...
        }

            ... //Other fields

    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("52693d98e7792c81a7f4e5ad"),
        "items" : {
            "user_id" : 6,
            "code" : "UXS08MIR6ZV",
            "name" : "Quisque Inc.",
            ...
        }
            ... //Other fields
    }
]
```

where `"_id"` is the `_id` of the parent document. The you can use `{$project: {...}}` to remove `_id` and extract interesting fields from `items` subdocument.

**Edit**

You could probably use simple `project`  at the beginning of the pipeline to reduce size of the documents going downstream.

```
db.store.aggregate([
    {$project: {"items": 1}},
    {$unwind: "$items"},
    {$project: {
        "user_id" : "$items.user_id",
        ...
    }}
]}
```

Comment: hey thanks that seem to do it. I kept trying to use the find method was my folly

Comment: quick question does it matter which place i put the unwind? can i have projections first. why does items have $ infront is this mapping to my items inside the store or just a variable name.

Comment: When you use aggregation framework order of the instructions usually matters. Sometimes it is only a matter of efficiency but in your case I don't think you can use `projection` first. `$` prefix means that you are referencing path in the document.

Comment: On second thought you could use simple `project` at the beginning of the pipeline. See edit for details.